# Systools aborted when generating upgrade with rebar

Tags: erlang, upgrade, rebar

I wanted to use rebar to release and upgrade my app in windows 7 and my erlang version is R15B. Following the wiki of rebar, I had already released a version. However, I came across a problem in doing upgrade. When I after typing this command:

```
rebar generate-upgrade previous_release=exemplar_1
```

it showed me this error:

```
ERROR: Systools [systools:make_tar/2] aborted with: [{error_add_appl,
                                                      {hipe,
                                                       {tar_error,
                                                        {add,
                                                         "f:/exemplar/rel/exemplar_1/lib/hipe-3.9/ebin/hipe.beam",
                                                         {"f:/exemplar/rel/exemplar_1/lib/hipe-3.9/ebin/hipe.beam",
                                                          enoent}}}}}]
ERROR: 'generate-upgrade' failed while processing f:/exemplar/rel: rebar_abort
```

Before typing this command, I replaced {start_phases, undefined} entry with {start_phases,[]} in all .app files.

I can't find anything helpful in google, so I ask for help here.

Comment: There is a recent thread on a similar issue in the erlang questions mailing list, http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2013-September/075508.html. I guess Hipe is disabled for windows which then triggers this bug.

Comment: Thank you! This really does great help for me! But why it seems that no one came across similar problem before, it's a common sense to enable hipe when install erlang?

Comment: HIPE doesn't seem to be enabled by default on Windows (it is on linux/unix), see http://www.erlang.org/doc/installation_guide/INSTALL.html#Using-HiPE. It might be that you can't use HIPE with Windows at all, the major platforms for Erlang are linux/unix.
Maybe combination of windows + release upgrades isn't very common, so no-one noticed before.